# Getting variable reference from fragment to activity

Tags: android, variables, android-fragments

I have an activity (MainActivity) that holds a Fragment (FragmentA) with an `ArrayList<Uri> array_list = new ArrayList<Uri>();`. 
How can my MainActivity get a reference of that array_list?

Now if you ask me why'd I want to get a reference of a variable of a fragment to an activity that holds that fragment, I'd say, I'm planning to get the items in array_list when I click the action button on my MainActivity.

I'm using ViewPager. I don't have fragment id's.

Comment: use interface as a callback to the activity

Comment: @Raghunandan - can you give me an example?

Comment: check http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html communicating with activity using callbacks. example is there is docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html&ei=jBf1UviZF_Pa0QXozYDIBg&usg=AFQjCNGQCzxA1VfoENYTJisTDtnWzl9hEA&sig2=zkLyAlGOlEf6JM_gMu8ViQ) is a good tuto :

**[Define an Interface then implement it in the activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#DefineInterface)**

> To allow a Fragment to communicate up to its Activity, you can define an interface in the Fragment class and implement it within the Activity. The Fragment captures the interface implementation during its onAttach() lifecycle method and can then call the Interface methods in order to communicate with the Activity.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the cleanest way you can do it is by using FragmentManager to retrieve attached fragment in an activity and then call getMyList() on that fragment to get list you want.

```
FragmentA fr = (FragmentA) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.my_fragment_a_id);
if(fr != null) {   
    List<Uri> list = fr.getMyList();
    // ... do some fun stuff
}
```

Note that it's not a good practice to keep a reference to the fragment out of the FragmentManager due to Activity lifecycle (you end up with a  reference to the fragment that has already been collected or you can prevent effective memory cleanup by GC).

Comment: This is the easiest and most elegant solution for accessing a fragment's variables.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Simply make
 ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList();
 as static variable like
 public static ArrayList array_list = new ArrayList(); 
and call this array from your MainActivity as
 FragmentA.array_list .

** Keep one thing remember that don't forget to clear this array whenever items in this array are added