# How to access fragment variable into main activity class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have 1 main activity class and 1 fragment class:

I want to access variable of fragment class into my main activity class:

Myfragment class:

```
public class DemoFragment extends Fragment {

Public String mydata="hello";
.. //other code
}
```

Mainactivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   ..//other code
   DemoFragment df;

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mContext = this;

        df = new DemoFragment();

        String newdata = df.mydata; //access from fragment but it shows null

    }

}
```

So how can i access fragment class variable values into main activity?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21634137/2435402

Comment: If you want to get the data on some actions then it will be always better to create an interface for communication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your fragment create

(a) Two fields:

```
listener mCallback;
Activity mActivity;
```

(b) Interface:

```
interface mydataBack(){
   public void bringBackString(String stringSentBack);
}
```

(c) Method

```
@Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            mActivity=activity;
            super.onAttach(activity);
        mCallback = (listener) mActivity;
        }`
```

Then in the Fragment call the method bringBackString(String) when you wish to send back the string.

In your mainactivity:

(a) add in the "implements.. ...listener" in the class declaration

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements DemoFragment.listener {  etc   and
```

(b) implement the interface method:

```
public void bringBackString(String stringBroughtBack){
....  do something with the string
}
```

Comment: onAttach(Activity) deprecated method, use onAttach(Context)

Answer (score -2):

you have yo use
 public static String mydata = "hello "
and then get it in activity by using df.mydata

Comment: this is a bad answer. Any other fragment in the activity also can then access mydata